# Select sum with input from grouped query

Tags: mysql

I need to make a query that selects a grouped collection of rows from a table based on user input conditions, and then in the select i will sum data from a subset of the rows.

The setup is rather expansive to describe in a post, so here is a demostration of the problem in the simplest way i can make it:

We have this table: DemoTable

| ID | StaticKey | GroupKey | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | 2 |
| 2 | A | A | 2 |
| 3 | A | B | 2 |
| 4 | A | B | 2 |
| 5 | A | C | 2 |
| 6 | A | C | 2 |

I make a select and groups on "StaticKey".
What i would then like to do, is to, in the select clause, to select the sum of a subset of the values from the groupped data:

```
select 
    DT.GroupKey,       
    (select sum(D.Value) from DemoTable D where D.ID in (DT.ID) and D.GroupKey = 'A') as 'Sum of A''s',
    (select COUNT(D.ID) from DemoTable D where D.ID in (DT.ID) and D.GroupKey = 'A')  as 'Count of A''s'
from DemoTable DT
group by DT.StaticKey;
```

I hoped that the sum would result in a sum of 4 and a count of 2, but i get 2 and 1. So the input to the "select sum" seems to be just one id and not the collected ids.

| GroupKey | Sum of A's | Count of A's |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |

If i add a group_concat of DT.ID i get them comma separated - but is it posible to get them as a collection i can use as input to the selects?

Heres sql to create the table and queries:

```
CREATE TABLE DemoTable
(
    ID        INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    GroupKey  varchar(200)     null     default null,
    StaticKey varchar(200)     not null default 'A',
    Value     varchar(200)     null     default null,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

insert into DemoTable (GroupKey, Value) values ('A', 2);
insert into DemoTable (GroupKey, Value) values ('A', 2);
insert into DemoTable (GroupKey, Value) values ('B', 2);
insert into DemoTable (GroupKey, Value) values ('B', 2);
insert into DemoTable (GroupKey, Value) values ('C', 2);
insert into DemoTable (GroupKey, Value) values ('C', 2);


select DT.GroupKey,
       (select sum(D.Value) from DemoTable D where D.ID in (DT.ID) and D.GroupKey = 'A') as 'Sum of A''s',
       (select COUNT(D.ID) from DemoTable D where D.ID in (DT.ID) and D.GroupKey = 'A')  as 'Count of A''s'
from DemoTable DT
group by DT.StaticKey;

DROP TABLE DemoTable;
```

Comment: `WHERE D.ID IN (SELECT id FROM DemoTable WHERE GroupKey = 'A')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simple:

```
select GroupKey,
       sum(Value) as sum_of_A,
       sum(GroupKey='A') as count_of_A
from DemoTable
where GroupKey='A'  
group by  GroupKey;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/sdYlTw57

Comment: Thanks! Dunno why i forgot that i can have functions within sum and count :)
Ended up going along with something like:
select DT.GroupKey,
       sum(DT.GroupKey = 'A') as 'Count of A',
       sum(if(DT.GroupKey = 'A', DT.Value, 0)) as 'Sum of A',
from DemoTable DT
group by DT.StaticKey;

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it always `D.ID in (DT.ID)`?

```
select 
    DT.GroupKey,       
    (select sum(D.Value) from DemoTable D where D.GroupKey = 'A') as 'Sum of A''s',
    (select COUNT(D.ID) from DemoTable D where D.GroupKey = 'A')  as 'Count of A''s'
from DemoTable DT
group by DT.StaticKey;
```

It does the job but perhaps it's too simple...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
SELECT DT.GroupKey,
SUM(DT.Value) AS 'Sum of A''s',
COUNT(DT.ID) AS 'Count of A''s'
FROM DemoTable DT
WHERE DT.GroupKey = 'A'
GROUP BY DT.StaticKey;
```